# Корректность использования взаимных указателей/ссылок на классы

Tags: c++, классы, архитектура, ссылки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли с моей стороны использовать нечто следующее:

```
class B;

class A {
    B* b;
};

class B {
    A& a;
};
```

Дело в том, что класс B не может существовать без класса A. То есть на некоторые классы A приходятся классы B. При этом класс B должен знать, кому он принадлежит. У меня есть два варианта решения сей проблемы:

1. Просто добавить сеттеры и геттеры к текущей логике, что позволит использовать что-то вроде такого: `a->getB()->doSomethingInBClass();`.
2. В классе B написать функцию, которая будет перебирать все существующие объекты классов A и определять, какому из этих объектов принадлежит объект класса B.

Но все-таки в глубине души есть какая-то надежда, что существует какой-нибудь шаблон для подобных случаев - просто я не смог его найти...

Comment: Использование сырого указателя - почти всегда некорректно. Используйте либо умный указатель, либо непосредственно `B`. Геттеры при необходимости к доступа к полю из вне понадобятся.

Comment: если два класса не могут жить друг без дружки, то может это все таки один класс или эти два класса нужно разбить на три? но для этого лучше озвучить реальное содержимое классов

Comment: Использование взаимных ссылок корректно в случае, если вы можете обосновать, зачем вам это нужно. Например, если вам нужно реализовать некоторый интерфейс, но вы не хотите наследовать от него A, чтобы не тащить этот интерфейс в заголовочный файл. Или если A уже реализует этот интерфейс для другой цели. Тогда вы создаёте B только для того, чтобы он реализовывал интерфейс через вызов методов A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так не устроит?

```
struct B;

struct A {
    A();
    B* b;
};

struct B {
    B(A& a):a(a){};
    A& a;
};

A::A()
{
    b = new B(*this);
}
```

Т.е. просто передавать классу `B` ссылку на его владельца-`A`? Ну, чуть на грани фола :), так как формально до завершения конструктора объекта `A` вроде как нет, но все будет нормально работать. И ничего не надо перебирать...

Или я неверно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Вы все верно поняли :) Именно ваш вариант и имелся в виду, просто я не уверен, что взаимные указатели/ссылки есть хорошо.